# How much time does it take to train a SVM classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I wrote the following code and tested it on small data:

```
classif = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='rbf'))
classif.fit(X, y)
```

Where `X, y`  (X - 30000x784 matrix, y - 30000x1) are NumPy arrays. On small data, the algorithm works well and gives me correct results.

But I started my program about 10 hours ago... And it is still in process.

I want to know how long it will take, or it stuck in some way?
(Laptop specs 4 GB Memory, Core i5-480M)

Comment: So uh...30000 dimensions and 30000 X 784 points....I have not really worked too long with machine learning but that is a pretty big and high dimensional feature vector...i do not think its too surprising its taking that long...you could try reducing the dimensions to speed it up...

Comment: @Roy Reducing the number of training instances would be *much* more effective than dimensionality reduction for kernel methods.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Would have to take your word on it, I'm not much more than a novice myself.

Answer (score 40):

SVM training can be arbitrarily long; this depends on dozens of parameters:

- `C` parameter - the greater the missclassification penalty, the slower the process
- Kernel - the more complicated the kernel, the slower the process (rbf is the most complex from the predefined ones)
- Data size/dimensionality - again, the same rule

In general, the basic SMO algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>), so in case of 30,000 datapoints it has to run a number of operations proportional to 2,700,000,000,000, which is a really huge number.

What are your options?

- Change the kernel to the linear one, 784 features is quite a lot, rbf can be redundant
- Reduce dimensionality of features (PCA?)
- Lower the `C` parameter
- Train the model on a subset of your data to find good parameters and then train the whole one on some cluster / supercomputer.

Comment: Kernel computation time is usually a non-issue when truly large problems are being considered. The difference between RBF and, say, polynomial is irrelevant. The only aspect of kernel complexity is linear vs others. Additionally, training complexity ranges from `O(n^2)` (smalll `C`) to `O(n^3)` (large `C`). Third, input dimensionality doesn't matter much in overall complexity (which is in function of number of training instances, not dimensionality).

Comment: Thank you. That parameter C makes algorithm working slower I wasn't thinking about. And didn' know that rbf is most complicated kernel - but it is true, when I change kernel on 'poly' it gave result in 2 hours.

Comment: @Marc - Thanks for the comments. There is a huge difference between RBF and polynomial - not because kernel function itself is complex, but that the induced RHKS is, and this is where the optimization takes place. Second, O(n^3) is the upper bound, obviously for small C it is faster. Third - dimensionality matters as it is inside a cost of each kernel computation (less important) and as it participates in complexity of the complexity of induced RHKS (more important)