# How can I tell if R is still estimating my SVM model or has crashed?

Tags: r, svm

I am using the library `e1071`. In particular, I'm using the `svm` function. My dataset has 270 fields and 800,000 rows. I've been running this program for 24+ hours now, and I have no idea if it's hung or still running properly. The command I issued was:

```
svmmodel <- svm(V260 ~ ., data=traindata);
```

I'm using windows, and using the task manager, the status of `Rgui.exe` is "Not Responding". Did R crash already? Are there any other tips / tricks to better gauge to see what's happening inside R or the SVM learning process?

If it helps, here are some additional things I noticed using resource monitor (in windows):

- CPU usage is at 13% (stable)
- Number of threads is at 3 (stable)
- Memory usage is at 10,505.9 MB +/- 1 MB (fluctuates)

As I'm writing this thread, I also see "similar questions" and am clicking on them. It seems that SVM training is quadratic or cubic. But still, after 24+ hours, if it's reasonable to wait, I will wait, but if not, I will have to eliminate SVM as a viable predictive model.

Comment: Please try to use standard English grammar, capitalization, & punctuation, etc., in writing your questions. It will make it easier for people to try to help you.

Comment: hopefully you will get help from experts but failing that my generic approach is to get the tool working for a smaller dataset, then try larger and larger ones, noting by how much the time is increasing (if necessary get enough data points to plot a graph).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165213/how-much-time-does-take-train-svm-classifier), "SVM training can be arbitrary long" depending on the parameters selected.

If I remember correctly from my ML class, running time is roughly proportional to the square of the number training examples, so for `800k` examples you probably do not want to wait.

Also, as an anecdote, I once ran `e1071` in `R` for more than two days on a smaller data set than yours. It eventually completed, but the training took too long for my needs.

Keep in mind that most ML algorithms, including SVM, will usually *not* achieve the desired result *out of the box*. Therefore, when you are thinking about how fast you need it to run, keep in mind that you will have to pay the running time every time you tweak a tuning parameter. 
Of course you can reduce this running time by sampling down to a smaller training set, with the understanding that you will be learning from less data.

Comment: This is an extremely informative answer, but it doesn't exactly explain how to tell if the library or R session has crashed.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander, That is a fair criticism, but I addressed the question of "how long is it reasonable to wait", so this does address the question, although not ALL of it.

Answer (score 1):

By default the function "svm" from e1071 uses radial basis kernel which makes svm induction computationally expensive. You might want to consider using a linear kernel (argument kernel="linear") or use a specialized library like [LiblineaR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LiblineaR/) built for large datasets. But your dataset is really large and if linear kernel does not do the trick then as suggested by others you can use a subset of your data to generate the model.